# Sending variables using sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I've started work on a simple newtworking project which creates a new thread for each connection and I'm trying to send multiple things across. What I'm wondering is there an easy way of simple say declaring a variable sending that whole variable to the server and that being sent to other clients. For example if I wanted to send a simple integer array? Basically how would I send an array or even an image across a socket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. What you are looking for is called serialization and can be used to send entire objects through a stream (socket, file, etc.). Have a look at [this java socket serialization tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/sockets/).

Check the docs on [ObjectOutpuStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) and [ObjectInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html).

Basically what you have to do is have any custom type that you want to be serialized implement the `Serializable` interface:

```
class MyCustomType implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

This is a marker interface that tells the runtime that this type can be sent over a stream.

Next, once your connections are set up you can obtain the socket input/output stream and write objects using `ObjectOutputStream`:

```
MyCustomType obj = new MyCustomType(); 
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(client.getOutputStream());
oos.writeObject(obj);
oos.flush();
```

or read them using `ObjectInputStream`:

```
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(client.getOutputStream());
MyCustomType obj = (MyCustomType) ois.readObject();
```

(`client` above is a `Socket`).

Comment: Oh I didnt realise I could send serilized objects over a socket! Thanks, one question though how straining would it be to send a serilized object quite often?

Comment: @Smallbro: Well serialization does carry a certain overhead, but I guess it depends on how "deep" the object is i.e. how many nested other objects need to be also serialized with it.

Comment: @Smallbro: This article http://blog.dynatrace.com/2011/03/02/behind-the-scenes-of-serialization-in-java/ suggests that if you keep sending objects of the same type then the metadata will be cached for subsequent invocations, thus leads to an acceptable overhead.